# How to append the new text into Textformfield, while getting text from the speech_to_text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text, flutter-textformfield

I am using speech_to_text plugin in flutter for converting speech into text. The extracted text is displaying into the Textformfield.
This is working fine, problem is that when I come back to convert the speech into text the previous text got erased. I want to append the new text into the previous one.

```
Future<void> _listenForSpeech() async {
bool isAvailable = await _speech.initialize();
if (isAvailable) {
  print("supported");
  bool isListening = await _speech.listen(
    onResult: (result) {
      setState(() {
        _isListening = true;
      

        _textFromSpeechController.text += result.recognizedWords;
  


      });
    },
  );
  if (!isListening) {
    setState(() {
      _speechText = 'Failed to start listening';
    });
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    _speechText = 'Speech recognition not available';
    print("not supported");
  });
 }
}
```

Textformfield

```
TextFormField(
   controller: _textFromSpeechController,
)

GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _listenForSpeech();
                startTimer();
                _isListening = true;
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                width: 150,
                height: 70,
                // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                            "assets/images/audio_rec_blue.png"))),
              ),
            ),


GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _stopVoiceListener();
                _resetTimer();
                setState(() {
                  _isListening = false;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 130,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/gifs/recording.gif"))),
              ),
            ),
```

Methods

```
 void _stopVoiceListener() {
 if (_isListening == true) {
  _isListening = false;
  _speech.cancel();
  // newText += "' ' ${_textFromSpeechController.text}";
 }
}
```

Comment: the above code work for me, means appending with previous text. is your TextFormField in same screen? by any chance did u reinit the controller in between? can you also print the value before and after this code  ' _textFromSpeechController.text += result.recognizedWords;'

Comment: Thank you for comment, I updated the question. Actually i am stoping the speech_to_text on stop button click and restarting on the start button click as show in the above code. The problem is that when coming again to start then the previous text got erased.